# System freezes on linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, freeze

I used to run an intel processor and amd gpu on a fedora distro on wayland. Everything was working fine and trouble free on that system. But then I changed my old system to ryzen 5 3500x + gtx1660 and installed the right drivers.

After that my system just started to freeze at random moments, at that moment nothing works except the mouse. I have to restart the computer, but it helps only for a while, then the same thing. I tried to install drivers through run file and cmd, but all to no avail. The drivers are nvidia 545.29.06.

I have changed several distributions and on all the picture is the same. At the moment I'm sitting on ubuntu 22.04. and I don't know how to fix this problem. I don't play games on linux, I need gpu power and capabilities for work. Help me solve my problem, I am not comfortable working on windows.

I tried to install drivers through run file and cmd, but all to no avail. The drivers are nvidia 545.29.06. I have changed several distributions and on all the picture is the same. At the moment I'm sitting on ubuntu 22.04. and I don't know how to fix this problem.

Comment: Here's the difference between then and now: Intel and AMD graphics work with open-source drivers that are installed and running in any mainstream Linux distro without ser intervention; NVIDIA requires proprietary drivers. Installing those is then a must and, with Secure Boot enabled (as it should be), users must also manually sign the modules. So, in a nutshell, 1. DON'T install from the Nvidia binaries unless you have to; you DON'T - Fedora has the proper Nvidia drivers version for your card in its repositories - so yo MUSTN'T. 2. Do your own research about exactly that.

Comment: As it is in its original form this question shows zero research. I'll delete this comment when and if you [edit] with some step yo may not be comfortable with when installing the required Nvidia drivers from the Fedora repo.

Comment: I put the drivers from the Fedora repository on a clean system, I put the drivers through ubuntu. Nothing works

Comment: It seems you didn't bother with the next step. Please read carefully in order to understand what yo need to do AFTER installing the drivers. Or, unless you're dual-booting with Windows 11 - in which case you must have Secure Boot enabled - you can disable Secure Boot in UEFI settings (NOT a recommendation). Can't be bothered to do what you need to do? Stick with Intel or AMD graphics, problem solved.

Comment: IT NOT SOLVE. 
In did absolutely everything as on the guides. Both on Ubuntu and on fedora and put it several times. 
I have a second system is windows 11 and there everything is fine, but on linux problems, more precisely on wayland, on xorg PC does not have to reboot, sometimes crashes desktop or applications crash, and have to log in again

Comment: You obviously didn't (or if the whatever guides you followed don't mention the need to sign the driver modules and/or reference Secure Boot they're incomplete, period). In any case never say "I did everything..." without actually DETAILING what you did and the results, it's quite frowned upon here. And to be clear: Again, you absolutely need the proprietary drivers, the fallback community driver `nouveau` does indeed freeze with some newer cards, especially in Wayland  - which had *acceptable* support only recently in the Nvidia drivers - and in order to have this drivers loaded (...)

Comment: (...) after installation you absolutely need to either use MOKutil in Debian/Ubuntu or equivalent in Fedora (that's your homework) to sign the drivers otherwise Secure Boot will prevent them from being used, i.e., the same as like they were never installed. Not understanding this is not an option, end of story. There's no other answer out there and nobody here will bother with such basic stuff.

Comment: I have secure boot disabled. That's not the problem.

Comment: Assuming it is a self build, did you take the correct & proper esd precautions? Did you use an earthed wriststrap? Were the components placed on anti-static surfaces? No to any of these and you may have zapped them with a few thousand volts.

Comment: Why did you even write that?